# Data Repitition in Dynamics CRM Run Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

every one I've created a report on case entity. Which will populate the related records of a particular case, while opening a case form.
Its doing the job but with a problem. It repeating the records. For example, If there are 7 related activities of a case like Email, call, Letter etc. It bringing up only the email for the 7 times.
I have the following query:

```
SELECT        
    activitytypecodename AS 'type', 
    regardingobjectidname AS 'regarding', 
    subject AS 'Subject', 
    statecodename AS 'status',
    prioritycodename AS 'priority', 
    new_casenumber AS 'casenumber'
FROM            
    FilteredActivityPointer AS CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer 
INNER JOIN
        FilteredIncident AS CRMAF_FilteredIncident 
ON 
    CRMAF_FilteredIncident.incidentid = CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer.regardingobjectid
```

And here what I have the results
[image]
Please give your kind suggestions and help to sort out the problem.

Comment: Can you share the query that you are using to bring up the records.

Answer (score 0):

try modifying the query to following

```
SELECT        
AP.activitytypecodename AS 'type', 
AP.regardingobjectidname AS 'regarding', 
AP.subject AS 'Subject'
--statecodename AS 'status',
--prioritycodename AS 'priority'
FROM     FilteredIncident AS CRMAF_FilteredIncident
INNER JOIN FilteredActivityPointer AS AP ON 
CRMAF_FilteredIncident.incidentid = AP.regardingobjectid
```

Comment: Thnx Piyus, the query was ok. there was nothing wrong with the query. but the problem was in expression. thats it was repeating the records. thnx for you kind assistance

Comment: great. So it is now resolved? btw one thing I needed to point you out was that `CRMAF_` prefix should only be used on the base table on which you are querying, i.e. just after the `FROM` keyword.